# I moved my iPhone photos to the PC and now I can only see AAE files

Tags: iphone, photos

I moved all my iPhone pictures to a PC because I was upgrading to a new IPhone and did no want to transfer all the photos to it.

After the pictures were moved to the PC, I deleted all the pictures from the old iPhone and started setting up the new one.

Few days later I wanted to organize the pictures and found out that I only have AAE files.

Can somebody tell me where the pictures could be ?

Comment: AAE files are metadata files that contain the edits to your photo. How did you move the photos from your iPhone to your PC? Do you have a backup of your iPhone prior to erasing it?

Comment: I cut and paste the photos to the PC. Sadly, I did not backup the iPhone. Question is why some of the folders that I cut- paste still have the photos and some folders do not ? Only containing the AAE files

Comment: By *cut-and-paste*, I am assuming you used Explorer and browsed your device for files.  Unfortunately, you needed to *synchronize* your iPhone to your PC because those (original) photos are held in the Photos library.  iOS does non-destructive edits and the AAE files are those edits (think of them as instructions), but they don’t contain an image.

Comment: Did you sync those photos to iCloud, OneDrive or something similar?

Comment: No, I did not… I always cut-paste my iPhone photos  to the PC without any issue. This time, I am still trying to figure out why I only got AAE files. I did not realize this mistake until I started to organize the photos

Comment: What if you go into Photos (on the old iPhone) and look in “Recently Deleted” folder.  Do you see anything there?